# Can't assign type int to type int*

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, int

I'm trying to write a code for a function that gets an array (lets call it arr1) with values between 32 and 64, and the size of the array(lets say size n). The function will sort the array in O(n).

The way I thought of doing this is to declare a second array (lets call it arr2) with size of 32 and do this:
for every index i between 0 and n, we put 1 in arr2 in the spot [arr1[i]-32]. so that for example, if for the current i, arr1[i]=40, then we put 1 in arr2 in the spot 40-32, 8.
Then we iterate through arr2, and if arr2[i]==1 then in arr[j] i put i+32, j++. in theory, arr1 should now be sorted.

my problem is the code, i get a little red line below the "=" when assigning values to arr2, and when I hover over it, it says "value of type int can't be assigned to type int*"

```
void sort_array(int* arr1,int n)
{
    int i=0,j=0;
    int* arr2[32];
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
        arr2[i]=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        arr2[arr1[i]-32]=1;
    for(i=0;i<32;i++)
        if(arr2[i]==1)
        {
            arr1[j]=i+32;
            j++;
        }
}
```

I'd also like to hear if someone has a better suggestion on how to sort this array in O(n). quicksort and mergesort are nlog(n)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
int* arr2[32];
```

This line should be

```
int arr2[32];
```

because `arr2` contains counters, not pointers. That is why assigning `1` to elements of `arr2` fails.

Now let's discuss your algorithm: your attempted implementation of [*counting sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) will break for arrays with duplicate values, because you set `arr2[arr1[i]-32]` to `1` regardless of how many times you found an item. You should change it to `arr2[arr1[i]-32]++`, and use the count to put that many counted values into the resultant array. See pseudocode in the wikipedia article a the correct implementation.

Here is [a table comparing performances of various sorting algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms). Look for the second table with details on non-comparison sorts.

Comment: Yeah that's right. Didn't think of duplicates, ++ does solve it. But what I meant is: is there a way to sort this array in O(n) without using another array, without declaring an arr2

Comment: @OriaGruber Not that I know of: all non-comparison sorts require a lot of additional memory. See the update to the answer; memory requirements are detailed in the fifth column of the Wikipedia page.

Comment: Thank you very much dasblinkenlight

Answer (score 0):

```
int *arr2[32];
```

should be

```
int arr2[32];
```

The former declares an array of 32 **pointers.**